# Error plotting data read from csv file

Tags: plot, octave

I am getting the followin error when trying to plot in GNU/octave:

```
octave:22> plot(b(:,2),b(:,4))
error: invalid conversion from real matrix to real scalar
error: __calc_dimensions__: expecting graphics handle as only argument
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/plot/private/__go_draw_axes__.m at line 55, column 8
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/plot/private/__go_draw_figure__.m at line 167, column 19
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.2/m/plot/__gnuplot_drawnow__.m at line 86, column 5
octave:23>
```

The variable *b* is loaded from a *csv* file, as follows:

```
b=csvread("my.csv")
```

Content of *my.csv*

```
1,40.0942,0.775539,18.658
2,40.1882,0.857556,415.677
3,40.2818,0.858294,233.934
4,40.3748,0.887273,348.503
5,40.4669,0.908618,27.0149
6,40.558,0.908496,234.81
7,40.6478,0.911826,58.3943
8,40.7362,0.922848,204.128
9,40.823,0.928547,7.75615
10,40.908,0.920065,0.0654867
```

Sadly,sometimes the erros happens, others do not. (octave bug?)

Does anyone knows what is going on?

By the way, my systems is: Ubuntu 12.11, octave 3.6.2, Linux kernel 3.5.00-22-generic

**Edit:**

I think it is a bug. The foregoing error is caused by a *plot* called after a *plotyy*. To reproduce the error, execute these commands:

```
1> b=csvread("my.csv");
2> plot(b(:,2),b(:,4))
3> plotyy(b(:,1),b(:,2),b(:,1),b(:,4))
4> plot(b(:,2),b(:,4))
```

Comment: Workarond: clf before last plot. 4> clf;plot(b(:,2),b(:,4))